# How to draw interactive timesheets in terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I have some data and I want to generate an interactive pictures from it in the terminal. How do I do that?

For example the data would be something like this:

```
Date,Start-time,End-time,Comment,Tag
2017-04-01,09:00,09:30,Read Newspaper,Read
2017-04-01,09:30,11:00,LT-103,Class
2017-04-01,11:00,11:10,Buy pens,Misc
2017-04-01,11:10,11:30,Stumble upon XYZ,Social
2017-04-01,11:30,12:00,Lunch,Upkeep
```

Then in the terminal I want to draw a picture like this:

[image: Example]

The association is that, to every tag I have a color code and as I process the rows of my data I want to print a color block of appropriate length on the terminal, one after another. (In the above, the picture doesn't correspond to the data and both are meant to be representative of an idea.)

So how does one print color blocks on terminals? Also I want the output display to be interactive (like in a terminal based game).

These are the interactions I want:

1. The screen will be too small to draw the records of the entire year. So I want to be able to scroll up or down using the keys <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> respectively.
2. I want to see the comment associated with each color block. I want to cycle through the previous comment or next comment using <kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd> respectively.

Comment: You aren't planning to do this in `bash`, I suppose? Take a look at "curses programming" in your programming language of choice, e.g. for Python: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html.

Comment: The screen can scroll back many years with the mouse wheel. The time frame depends on how many lines you allocate to terminal display history.

Comment: You should put the description of what you were doing inside the color block too. For each group I would store the foreground and background color codes in an array kept on disk.